# Blocks freeze my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks

I have one minor problem with my app.

When I use my block, the application is freezing a long time (almost 1 minutes), and so we can do nothing, all of the scroll / button / etc. are not working.

I want to optimize my code, to make it work faster, and the user don't have to wait for 1 minutes

```
- (IBAction)exporter:(id)sender {
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Accès aux calendrier" message:@"L'accès au calendrier est nécessaire pour utiliser cette fonctionnalité" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }


    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];

    Variables *objStatutCompte = [Variables getStatutCompte];

    if([objStatutCompte.statutCompte isEqualToString:@"clt"])
    {
        NSString* titreEvent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intervention avec %@", intervenantRecup];
        event.title=titreEvent;

    }
    else if([objStatutCompte.statutCompte isEqualToString:@"slr"])
    {
        NSString* titreEvent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intervention chez %@", clientRecup];
        event.title=titreEvent;
    }

    NSString* lieuEvent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", adresseClientRecup, villeRecup];


    event.location=lieuEvent;

    NSString* currentDay = [dateRecup substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
    NSInteger jourCourant = [currentDay integerValue];

    NSString* currentMonth = [dateRecup substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,2)];
    NSInteger moisCourant = [currentMonth integerValue];

    NSString* currentYear = [dateRecup substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,4)];
    NSInteger anneeCourante = [currentYear integerValue];

    NSString* dateDebut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%02d %@:00", anneeCourante, moisCourant, jourCourant, heureDebutRecup];
    NSString* dateFin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%02d %@:00", anneeCourante, moisCourant, jourCourant, heureFinRecup];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:nil];
    NSDate* dateD = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateDebut];

    NSDate* dateF = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateFin];

    event.startDate=dateD;
    event.endDate=dateF;

    NSMutableArray *myAlarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600]; // 1 Hour
    [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];

    event.alarms=myAlarmsArray;

    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Evénement ajouté"
                                                    message:@"L'évenement a bien été ajouté"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}];
```

}

Comment: Did you discover on which line it waits and why so long?

Comment: @user623396, No i don't know how to use the debug tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `requestAccessToEntityType` says:

> When the user taps to grant or deny access, the completion handler will be called on an arbitrary queue. Your app is not blocked while the user decides to grant or deny permission.

The key to this is that the `completionHandler` may not be called on the main queue, but all UI updates must take place on the main thread.

Therefore you should dispatch your UI code to the main queue:

```
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) { 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // your code here
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) User Instruments->Time Profiler tool to detect problem part of app:
In Xcode menu Build->Profile, then select Time Profiler tool, then start record. Use app as usual, and then stop record. In the bottom right corner you'll need to check such settings:
"Invert Call Tree", "Hide Missing Symbols". Then find what function use most of the CPU time

2) In my experience it can happens, if you use some framework (for example - SDWebImage), block some thread for operations, and you try to execute something in this thread. Also it can happens in main thread...

Comment: As an aside, rather than looking for CPU usage, I might suggest the "record waiting threads" feature of Instruments. Sometimes you can have blocking that doesn't manifest itself as CPU usage and also there can be legitimate CPU usage unrelated to blocked calls. I suspect that "record waiting threads" might get to the heart of the issue more quickly. I personally suspect that the issue rests in his calling UI methods from background queue, but if not, "record waiting threads" is useful.